# AS3 multiple file download, check when completed?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am looping through a small array of file names to grab from a remote server and save locally. This bit works OK.

The problem is, I need to run my next function when the downloads are complete.

Currently, my function, lets call it step2(), gets called before all the FileStreams can finish (infact, its called before that function even starts!)

I read that there is a complete event listener when using openAsynch, but I need to check that all files, e.g. 3 remote swfs) have been written and then start step2() function.

How can I go about this?

Code below:

```
function onPlaylistComplete(e:Event)
{
    var myArray:Array = new Array();
    for each(var i in list_of_files)
    {
        myArray.push(i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        swfItem = myArray[i];
        var urlString:String =  site_url + myArray[i];
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();

        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlStreamComplete(swfItem));
        urlStream.load(urlReq);
    }

    function urlStreamComplete(swfItem):Function
    {
        var downloadSwf:Function = function (event:Event):void {
            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var stream = event.target;
            stream.readBytes(fileData, 0, stream.bytesAvailable);
            try {
                var f : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(swfItem);
                var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
                fs.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCompleteHandler);
                fs.openAsync(f, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(fileData);
            }
            catch (err : Error) {
                trace(err.message);
            }
        }
        return downloadSwf;
    }

    function fileCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
        e.target.close();
    }

    step2(); // this seems to run before UrlStreamComplete()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your `for loop` it will never work with Async model. so better need work to with recursive function.

downloadAllFiles method second arg that is function called when all download are completed.Then you can call step2() or whatever may be.

Make sure if any problem while download file like IOErrorEvent,etc...

```
    downloadAllFiles(myArray,function():void
    {
        step2();
    });

    function downloadAllFiles(myArray:Array, complete:Function):void
    {
        if(myArray && myArray.length == 0)
        {
            if(complete)
                complete.call();
            return;
        }

        swfItem = myArray.shift();

        var urlString:String =  site_url + swfItem;
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();

        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void 
        {
            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var stream = event.target;
            stream.readBytes(fileData, 0, stream.bytesAvailable);

            try {
                var f : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(swfItem);
                var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();

                fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, function(closeEvent:Event):void
                {
                    downloadAllFiles(myArray,complete);
                    return;
                });
                fs.openAsync(f, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(fileData);
            }
            catch (err : Error) 
            {
                trace(err.message);
            }
        });

        urlStream.load(urlReq);
    }
```

Comment: How do i get it to loop through the array (myArray). It looks like it only runs once. I tried the code and it only downloaded one swf file. IOErrorEvent gave me - "IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #3013: File or directory is in use."

Comment: Look at this line swfItem = myArray.shift(); which return always first value of array and remove it so we can traverse all item in the myArray. Make sure your file stream is closed or if any other process use those file if not(I am not sure you can try restart your system).

Comment: I got it working now :) although one little problem - I get an error with the URL stream after my files are downloaded, i caught the error and it is trying to load a file from "http://www.mydomain.com/null" which obviously doesn't exist. Otherwise, it works great!

Comment: Ohh IOErrorEvent with urlStream me thought it associated with FileStream error. if you accept it is answer then mark.

Comment: i put error handlers on both urlstream and filestream. i get an error showing up on urlstream because after download 3 correct files, it tries to download a file form the URL i mentioned in my above comment. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think so clean your project then build or check with error handler.

Comment: i did check with the handler, and I've explained the error. I am guessing it is possibly the downloadAllFiles function trying to run once more after the array is empty?

Comment: Great you are right return statement need to add after complete.call(); me updated please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move step2(); at the end of fileCompleteHandler function?
Because at this point step2(); is called right after going through for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
 loop (Which is way to early).

Comment: This is my point, I am unsure on the process. I have just tried with step2(); inside the fileCompleteHandler function, and it doesn't seem to work/advance to the actual step2() function. Any idea?

Comment: yup, I'd add counter just before this for loop and then in fileCompleteHandler i'd check if all were finished. If yes fire step2();

Comment: Hmm, it seems my event listener for the FileStream isn't working? I removed the step2(); function and added in a simple trace() = nothing :/

Comment: so maybe you can add also progress event to check how it's going?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is a way to check that all files from your list are loaded, **3vliguy** is right and your `step2();` should be in the complete handler but, not alone, you have to also test if ALL files are loaded. you can do it in various ways, e.g. use file counter and when it is 0 (all files loaded) you will execute `step2()` else you will ignore it and just decrease counter.

p.s. the **Raja Jaganathan** way will work as well, only it is queued loading whereas with the counter you can start loading of all files at the beginning.